# Host WCF Service on Public Ip

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I have created a WCF service on my local and host the service on IIS so that I can invoke my WCF service from other PC. Both PCs are under the same router. I am able to call WCF service on my local but not able to browse the same service from other PC.

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings />
  <connectionStrings />
  <system.web>
    <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate.

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
        <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
              applications.

          <profileService enabled="true"
                          readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                          writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
        <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
      </webServices>
      <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>        
      <service name="WcfStudentService.StudentService" behaviorConfiguration="WcfStudentService.StudentServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address=""  binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfStudentService.IStudentService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
              <!--<dns value="123.236.41.136" />-->
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfStudentService.StudentServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>      
  </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="StudentService.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**StudentService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfStudentService
{
    // StudentService is the concrete implmentation of IStudentService.
    public class StudentService : IStudentService
    {
        List<StudentInformation > Students = new List<StudentInformation>() ;

        // Create  list of students
        public StudentService()
        {
            Students.Add(new StudentInformation(1001, "Nikhil", "Vinod"));
            Students.Add(new StudentInformation(1002, "Joshua", "Hunter"));
            Students.Add(new StudentInformation(1003, "David", "Sam"));
            Students.Add(new StudentInformation(1004, "Adarsh", "Manoj"));
            Students.Add(new StudentInformation(1005, "HariKrishnan", "Vinayan"));
        }

        // Method returning the Full name of the student for the studentId
        public string GetStudentFullName(int studentId)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> Student
                         = from student in Students
                           where student.StudentId == studentId
                           select student.FirstName + " " + student.LastName;

            return Student.Count() != 0 ? Student.First() : string.Empty; 
        }

        // Method returning the details of the student for the studentId
        public IEnumerable<StudentInformation> GetStudentInfo(int studentId)
        {

            IEnumerable<StudentInformation> Student =  from student in Students
                                                       where student.StudentId == studentId
                                                       select student ;
            return Student;
        }


    }
}
```

**IStudentService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfStudentService
{
    // Defines IStudentService here
    [ServiceContract ]
    public interface IStudentService
    {

        // Define the GetStudentFullName OperationContact here….
        [OperationContract]
        String GetStudentFullName(int studentId);

        // Define the GetStudentInfo OperationContact here….
        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<StudentInformation> GetStudentInfo(int studentId);

    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class StudentInformation
    {
        int _studentId ;
        string _lastName;
        string _firstName;

        public StudentInformation(int studId, string firstname, string lastName)
        {
            _studentId = studId;
            _lastName = lastName;
            _firstName = firstname;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int StudentId
        {
            get { return _studentId; }
            set { _studentId = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I google this issue and found many similar issues but not able to understand the resolution of mine. One [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738201/wcf-hosting-with-ip-address) I found little helpful but still not able to get it.

My service host on 192.168.X.XXX:82 , when I browse the same on other PC it shows "Network Issue". Please help me to get out from this.

Comment: What do you mean by "browse the same on other PC"?

Comment: Actually I want to access this Service on other project so I want to try to invoke my service from other PC.

Comment: can you ping that IP address from other computers?

Comment: You mean  by that IP address means on which I have hosted my Service right?

Comment: No, it shows "Request Time Out"

Comment: how you expect to connect to a service hosted somewhere when you can not see that PC in network? It is possible in some cases that the network administrator blocks the ability to ping other computers but in your case I think the problem is that you can not access the PC which the service is hosted on. Please check network connection and check if you can access the PC you are trying to host your service on it and then when you are able to do that give it a try again

Comment: Yes I am totally agree with you, but I am asking the same that what should I do to access my service from other PCs as well.

Comment: This is not related to stackoverflow. maybe you should ask this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Port 82 is probably blocked by windows firewall. Host on port 80 or add a firewall rule. Of course there could be 10 other connection problems, of which, this is just one.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an Inbound and Outbound Rules on my system and allow Port 82 for "Domain, Private and Public". You can set the Rules "**Control Panel-->All Control Panel Items->Windows Firewall-->Advance Settings**".

Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: Can you please specify how you had specified the rules?